# Call top level function from groovy method

Tags: groovy

I figure this has a simple answer, but my web searching couldn't find it.

If I've got the following ([ideone](http://ideone.com/HVR89L)):

```
def f() {}

class C
{
    public h() { f() }
}

x = (new C()).h();
```

This fails with the following error:

```
No signature of method: c.f() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

How do I call `f()` from inside a method of `C`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a reference to the "outer" class (which isn't really an outer class).

Assuming you are writing your code in a `Script.groovy` file, it generates two classes: `C.class` and `Script.class`. There is no way to the `C` call the `f()` method, since it has no idea where it is defined.

You have some options:

**1)** @MichaelEaster's idea, giving a metaclass defition from the current scope (i.e. `Script`)

**2)** Create/pass a `Script` object inside `C`:

```
def f() { "f" }

class C
{
    public h(s = new Script()) { s.f() }
}

assert "f" == new C().h()
```

**3)** Make `C` an inner class (which also needs an instance of `Script`:

```
class Script {
  def f() { "f" }

  class C
  {
      public h() { f() }
  }

  static main(args) {
    assert "f" == new C(new Script()).h()
  }
}
```

**4)** Static inner class plus static `f()`:

```
class Script {
  static def f() { "f" }

  static class C
  {
      public h() { f() }
  }

  static main(args) {
    assert "f" == new C().h()
  }
}
```

Comment: Plus @dmahapatro's answer :-)

Comment: Well explained. I can hardly give this explanation from my phone, so I proposed an easy one. ;)

Comment: As a special case, if you're using Jenkins and Groovy scripting for the Pipeline plugin, you can look up the method as a DSL object if you passed a reference to the calling pipeline in. You use the same method as accessing any other step from a class.

Comment: Script is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, without using `metaClass` is to define `h()` as a closure and use:

```
def f() {}
class C {     
   def h = { f() } 
}  
x = (new C()).h
x.delegate = this

x()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, using meta-programming:

```
def f() {  println "Hello" }

class C
{
    public h() { f() }
}

C.metaClass.f = { f() }

x = (new C()).h();
```