# How to define class in Jenkinsfie

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a jenkins pipeline in order to do some continuous integration and automated deployement.
Since I'm using Gitea, I have installed gitea plugin and configured it to execute my jenkins file pipeline.
So far, so good.

I have managed to code something that "work" but the code is horrible and I have to heavely use global variable and other "bad" thing.

So I thougth that rewrite the pipeline but using class in order to keep thing clean was a good idea, but I ended up running into one problem after another !
The problem is that I'm not reallu use to code in Groovy and I'm currently discovering Jenkins.

First, I failed to know where to declare the class, so I just put it outside the pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('blabla') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def var = new MyClass()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class MyClass {

    /* Some propeties, methods ... */
}
```

Is this the rigth place or are there any other one ?

Secondly, when the class is declared like in my previous example, the security plugin / jenkins sandbox will stop my pipeline if I'm using "echo" or "println" in my class method.

```
    pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {

            stage('blabla') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        def var = new MyClass()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class MyClass {

        def MyClass()
        {
            echo "This echo will make my pipeline fail"
        }
    }
```

give me

> Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject
>   invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (MyClass echo
>   java.lang.String). Administrators can decide whether to approve or
>   reject this signature.

I don't understand why I can't call su a basic function, I'm guessing it's a matter of scope (since the class declaration is outside the "pipeline" block) but I haven't find a way to make it work cleanly.
I'm not a fan of approuving this security exception througth Jenkins, nor I'm a fan about disabling Jenkins sandbox.
Why can't I use a simple "echo" ??? It's the same thing about "println" ...

Lastly, it seem I'm not able to call my own function declared at the same level ...

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('blabla') {
            steps {
                script {

                    MyFunc() // This work

                    def var = new MyClass()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def MyFunc()
{
    return sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -lsa')
}

class MyClass {

    def MyClass()
    {
        MyFunc() // This doesn't work ...
    }
}
```

> Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject
>   invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (MyClass MyFunc).
>   Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

The heck ? What I am missing so badly that I can't even use basic function or my own function in the pipeline ??

Comment: So this is a really verbose question that maybe should be reduced, but I see two issues when I skim it. This section of documentation can assist on where to place classes: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure. Your specific error is related to a security issue that has to do with whether you are running in sandbox mode and/or whether you have admin to approve script usage. You can search Stack Overflow for various answers on how to deal with "Scripts not permitted to use method ..."

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I understand correctly, I need to do a shared library if I want to use a class, and I need to run the pipeline without the sandbox ... If this is really the case, then I'm dumbfounded to such complexity ...

Comment: You do need to run outside of sandbox mode unless you retrieve and load the library independent of the admin config.

Comment: or you permit every signature individually. The error message contains a link to the Script Approval page.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Jenkins shared library and put the class there.

See more information of how to use it in: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

The error message is highly misleading.

When you get a "Scripts not permitted to use" error that is specifically about `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod`, it doesn't mean what it seems to mean. (Unless you're actually literally using invokeMethod because you want to do some weird dynamic method call stuff)

Almost always, when you see this error what it means is that you tried to invoke a method on a class that doesn't have that method. Here, the error should really tell you "`MyClass` doesn't have a method called `MyFunc`", but the security system got in the way and threw up a the error you got instead.

The general issue of "how do I invoke a top-level function from inside a groovy-defined class" is covered here: [Call top level function from groovy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651114/call-top-level-function-from-groovy-method)

Short version: yes, you should put the function in a shared library, but the security error is just a red herring.

(Note: if you get a "Scripts not permitted to use" error that is **not** about `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod`, that is an honest permissions error and you'll likely need an admin of your Jenkins instance to approve your script or blanket approve the method it's talking about)